# How to redirect to an external site with a Nuxt middleware?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, middleware, server-side-rendering

I would like to redirect a certain group of users to another URL (external) before the page is loaded, i.e. with middleware.
Since I use nuxt in ssr-mode and redirect the users in layouts/default via `window.location.replace()`, you see the "mainsite" for a second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of middleware should do the trick and you won't see any content displayed before because it will be executed before rendering your page.

`middleware/google.js`

```js
export default ({ redirect }) => {
  if (myCoolCondition === 'cool') {
    redirect('https://www.google.com')
  }
}
```

To apply it to a specific component/page, use this

```html
<script>
export default {
  middleware: ['google']
}
</script>
```

Here is the related documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware#named-middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `navigateTo` method with the `external` options set to `true`, like the following:

```js
return navigateTo(EXTERNAL_URL, {
  external: true
})
```

Reference: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to#external-url