# I need redirect before load page and show html elements

Tags: nuxt.js

I use this code for redirect

```js
beforeCreate() {
  if (this.$store.state.user.user.id != null) {
    this.$router.push('/')
  }
}
```

my this.$store.state.user.user.id valued in middleware with this code.

```js
import {GET_CARD, GET_USER} from "../store/types/action-types";
export default async function ({store}) {
  await store.dispatch('cart/' + GET_CARD)
  await store.dispatch('user/user/' + GET_USER)
}
```

if user logged in show page for 0.5 sec and next redirect. i need dont show login page and next redirect.
tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer could maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68858238/8816585 (posted minutes ago)

This kind of middleware should work

```js
export default ({ store, redirect }) => {
  if (store.state.user.user.id) {
    redirect({ name: 'index' }) // or redirect('/')
  }
}
```